# Auto generate entity model from database to current DbContext class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

I am working on CodeFirst and have auto-generated the DbContext and Entities models for the first time.

[image: Selected Code First from database.]

It successfully generated Entity Models:

[image: ACL_Action.cs, App.config, and ModelContext.cs.]

But for awhile, the Database has had some new tables, and I have had to generate new C# Entity models. Currently, there is no way allow me to automatically generate a new Entity class for the existing DbContext.

Would you please advise me on it?

Answer (score 0):

You have three options (to my knowledge):

1. Delete DbContext and existing models and regenerate from scratch. If you haven't made any changes to the default context or entities this is an easy approach.
2. Generate a new model and copy and paste the DbSets and model configurations into your existing DbContext. Then you can just delete the newly generated context.
3. [EntityFramework Migrations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/migrations/) - Once you have the database created you can make future updates to your code-first model and then apply them to your database rather than the other way around.